# I want to save a text input field into local storage and then display the value on an other .html page

Tags: javascript, html

I´m a beginner and for my first project I´d like to make a text based game. 
I´d like the player to input his name into a  field and then display his name on following pages.
I choose to to this with localStorage because I do not know any server-side programming yet.
If possible, I would like to not use a javascript library.

I think, I´m gettin the value of the user the right way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  // Gets input value
  var uName = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  // Saves data to retrieve later
  localStorage.setItem("userName", uName);

  // Updates HTML
  updateHTML();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

set user name: 
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Answer</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

The second page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function getName() {
  return localStorage.getItem("userName");
}

function updateHTML() {
  var uName = getName();
  document.getElementById("storedName").innerHTML = uName;
}

</script>
</head>

<body class=backgroundcomputer001>

    "Welcome back <p id="storedName"></p>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I already spent more than two days on this problem. 
Any help appreciated. 
( I know that I should keep the javascript and the html seperated, but it is more easy for me to visualize what is happening.)

Comment: As a hint: Your function updateHTML() does not exist on your first page. And on the second page, you don't call updateHTML().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first the `updateHTML` function is not called anywhere. You have declared it but haven't called it. You can add `updateHTML();` to the end of your script and it will be executed. The second problem is that even in this case the code wouldn't be able to display the name because of the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

This means that at the moment the function was executed the document wasn't still completely loaded. As a solution you can put your script just before closing body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body class=backgroundcomputer001>
  <div>
    Welcome back <p id="storedName"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
   function getName() {
     return localStorage.getItem("userName");
   }

   function updateHTML() {
     var uName = getName();
     document.getElementById("storedName").innerHTML = uName;
   }

   updateHTML();

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. For other readers: You can omit the updateHTML function on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the function `updateHTML()`, what you need is to redirect to the following HTML and you have to do it with this instruction:

```
window.location.href = "index.html"; // name of your html that presents the username
```

And for the HTML where it presents the user name, add a function that is executed when it finishes reloading the HTML, like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function() { //This function is executed when loading the page
        var uName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
        document.getElementById("storedName").innerHTML = uName;
    }
</script>
```

And to present the name and this next to the welcome you can do it like this

```
<p>"Welcome back <span id="storedName"> </span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the window.location call as a part of myFunction. Now the user uploads its name and is directly redirected. 
I did not implement the window.onload part but used the solution by @holymoof.